# a simple css positioning system. trying to align them perfectly and even

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, css, web-applications

Hi guys I am pretty much trying to do 3 boxes aligned perfectly even with each-other but I am not sure why it keeps moving out of place

I have a .clear class on it but still wont become even and the middle one goes down

this is my html and my css in order

```
      <div id="left3box">
        <p> hello i am left
      </div>
      <div id="middle3box">
        <p> hello i am middle
      </div>
      <div id="right3box">
        <p> hello i am right
      </div>
     <div class="clear"></div>
```

and my css

```
#thirdbox {
  border: solid 4px black;
  margin: 60px;
}

#left3box{
 width: 300px; border: 1px solid red; float: left; margin-right: 30px;
}

#middle3box{
 width: 300px; border: 1px solid red; margin: auto;

}

#right3box{
 width: 300px; border: 1px solid red; float: right; margin-right: 30px;
}
```

Comment: i have a.class clear in my css as well forgot to list it

Answer (score 0):

If you want the 3 boxes to distribute evenly you are probably better off removing the 'floats', make them 'dispay:inline-block' set the parent element to 'text-align:center', then use the 'margin' on the div's to decide the spacing between them

The code you have supplied may work, depending on the width of the parent container

Answer (score 0):

Using margin and floats the middle box should come after the left and right one in the markup.

Answer (score 0):

Add a margin-right and margin-left to your middle column, adjust it so it lines up exactly how you want it. So something like

```
.rightColumn
{ 
border: 1px solid red;  
width: 300px; 
float: left;
}
.leftColumn
{
border: 1px solid red;
width: 300px;
float:left;
color:#7D26CD;  
}
.middleColumn
{
border: 1px solid red;
margin-right: 10px;
margin-left: 10px;
width: 300px; 
float: left;
}
```

another reason it mightmove outof place is if the margin-right you have in the leftand right box is too wide, therefore there isn't enough room for all 3. so just fiddle around with that.